# Docker run uses host PATH when chaining commands

Tags: docker

I have written an image that bundles utils to run commands using several CLIs. I want to run this as an executable as follows:

`docker run my_image cli command`

Where CLI is my custom CLI and command is a command to that CLI.

When I build my image I have the following instruction in the Dockerfile:

`ENV PATH="/cli/scripts:${PATH}"`

The above works if I do not chain commands to the container. If I chain commands it stops working:

```
docker run my_image cli command && cli anothercommand

Command 'cli' not found, but can be installed with...
```

Where the first command works and the other fails.

So the logical conclusion is  that `cli` is missing from path. I tried to verify that with:

`docker run my_image printenv PATH`

This actually outputs the containers PATH, and everything looks alright. So I tried to chain this command too:

`docker run my_image printenv PATH && printenv PATH`
And sure enough, this outputs first the containers PATH and then the PATH of my system.

What is the reason for this? How do I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type a command into your shell, your local shell processes it first before any command gets run.  It sees (reformatted)

```sh
docker run my_image cli command \
  && \
cli anothercommand
```

That is, your host's shell picks up the `&&`, so the host first runs `docker run` and then runs `cli anothercommand` (if the container exited successfully).

You can tell the container to run a shell, and then the container shell will handle things like command chaining, redirections, and environment variables

```sh
docker run my_image sh -c 'cli command && cli anothercommand'
```

If this is more than occasional use, also consider writing this into a shell script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cli command
cli another command
```

`COPY` the script into your Docker image, and then you can `docker run my_image cli_commands.sh` or some such.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! Clear explanation and two solutions to the problem, thanks a lot!